# Is it possible to write a script which will make Windows 7 open a non-xls file with Excel?

Tags: python, windows, excel, file

I'd like to know if it is possible to write a python script which will make Windows 7 open a non-xls file with Excel, such as:

```
file_path = somefile
open_file_with_excel(filepath)
```

The script should find Excel application, because Excel's installation directory is not same in every PC.

Comment: I know some of you have itchy fingers to close questions, at least let me get an answer for it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If excel is on your path than just `subprocess.Popen([r'path_to_file'])` will do the job.
If the file is not associated with excel then you would need to use:

```
subprocess.Popen(['excel', r'path_to_file'])
```

or if excel is not on the path:

subprocess.Popen([r'path_to_excel', r'path_to_file'])

Comment: But the file is not an .xls file

Comment: @alwbtc add file extension to "open with" and make exel default.

Comment: @eri No, i'm not going to do that, because it is a text file.

Comment: @alwbtc save it as csv

Comment: @Steve Barnes what does `r` mean here? and how do I write it if `path_to_file` is a variable, such as `path_to_file="C:\myfile"` then `subprocess.Popen(['excel', r path_to_file])`?

Comment: Path to file is the complete path to the file including the drive, directory, filename & extension e.g. `C:\mydir\Fred.txt` - this needs to be stored in a string and the `\`s will have special meaning unless escaped by either doubling all the `\`s or by prefixing the string with the letter `r` - the string can be stored in a variable e.g. `my_var = r'C:\mydir\Fred.txt'` and then used.

Answer (score 3):

I believe so:

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = 1
xl.Workbooks.open('filename')
```

Importing pywin32: [How to install pywin32 module in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863056/how-to-install-pywin32-module-in-windows-7)

Advanced python+excel: http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html

Comment: win32com very is useful if you need to actually manipulate the contents of a file within excel but under python control - I have however had a couple of IDEs and other packages moan about it being installed as it seems it can cause them some problems.