# No module named 'win32api'

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.x, module, win32com

In Python 3.4 from Anaconda, I created a program and it is giving me and import error each time I run it. 
Using Spyder.

ImportError: No module named 'win32api'

I already have the pywin32 installed. And I can see the win32api.pyd under C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\win32

This is the import code on my program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import requests #needs to be installed
import pymysql #needs to be installed
import csv 
import win32com.client #needs to be installed

import datetime
```

This is the whole error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
import win32api, sys, os

ImportError: No module named 'win32api'
```

This is the only instance of Python I have installed. I uninstalled everything else and installed only Anaconda.

Searching online I got to something that said that it could be a problem with the PYTHONPATH. But honestly, I have no idea what they are talking about.
So any noob help would be really appreciated.
I am using Windows 7 by the way.

Thank you

Comment: Did you install pywin32 separately or was it included in anaconda?

Comment: Hello, sorry I didn't answer. 
At the end, it didn't work. So I ended up installing WinPython.
But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The installation for pywin32 must have failed, or it is not for same OS bit architecture (say anaconda 64 bit and pywin32 32 bit). I recommend

1. you uninstall pywin32,
2. check what bit version of anaconda you are using, then
3. install pywin32 for same version,
4. verify that the installer indicates 100% success and there are no errors flagged in the installer's log window (it's rare but something may fail and the installer doesn't know).
5. Then open a python console and type "import win32com".

If #5 fails to import win32com, then:

1. try installing a different version of python, for example from python.org
2. repeat steps 2 to 5 above but for new python instead of anaconda

Could be that anaconda distributors did something to the python interpreter (although I didn't think so), or that some libs aren't registered right (see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17061853/869951 for some more things to try).

Comment: I installed winpython instead of anaconda at the end. Thank you

Comment: may just need a reboot: it was the case for me

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it installing the module pywin32:

In a normal python:

```
pip install pywin32
```

In anaconda:

```
conda install pywin32
```

My python installation (Intel® Distribution for Python) had some kind of dependency problem and was giving this error. After installing this module I never more saw it.

Comment: pip install pypiwin32

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by outforawhile in comment, simply restarting the laptop fixed this for me.

It may be that this is required for Windows to register the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

try this before install pywin32

```
pip install pywinutils
```

Answer (score 0):

close the python idle's and run the file again works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).