# No module named 'win32api' // PY2EXE

Tags: python, winapi, pyinstaller

I am using Python 3.6.7 in conda 4.5.12 (Win10,64bit) and I want to compile my Python project to an .exe-File using Pyinstaller (3.5 dev). I keep getting the same error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
[65600] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_win32comgenpy
```

I already reinstalled **pywin32** as recommended in [25314463](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314463/no-module-named-win32api), the import of **win32com** works. 
I also tried:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

as described in [21343774](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343774/importerror-no-module-named-win32api). The Installation was successful. But I still get the same Error.

```
pip install pywin32
```

from [827](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/827) does not solve the problem either.
Also I tried to import **win32api**, **win32com** and **pywin32** in my .spec-file with the matching paths, but still no success.

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happened to me on Windows that installed package is not visible. Try first uninstalling it:

```
pip uninstall pypiwin32
```

Make sure it has been removed:

```
pip list
```

Then install from scratch:

```
pip install --no-cache pypiwin32
```

Make sure it is installed:

```
pip list
```

You might see `pywin32` in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately this doesnt solve my problem. The error persists.

When I initially try to execute the progamm the error appears:
_ERROR loading Python DLL (python36.dll)_
But after added this DLL to the folder, this error disappears.

Does this may have something to do with the win32api error?

Comment: That's strange behavior, maybe you have a mix of Python version onboard? In this case it can happen with you to install library to another Python. I would try 1) reinstall Python  2) install library in a clean virtual env

Answer (score 0):

Just `pypiwin32` didn't do it for me. It worked only when I uninstalled all libs related to pywin32 and then installed again