# Auto-Py-To-Exe - win32api - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, winapi, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I have been attempting to compile a python project that uses these imports

```
import os
import numpy
import sys
import pytube
import time
from moviepy.editor import *
```

I have installed all of them via pip and I have also been looking around for trouble shooting tips but none of them seem to work. I keep getting this error when executing the built executable via Auto-py-to-exe.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py", line 49, in <module>
    import win32com
  File "c:\users\*****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
[17344] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_win32comgenpy
```

Anyone know a way to fix it?

Comment: Have you installed `win32` package? Try `pip install pypiwin32`

Comment: Yes,It seems that you didn't install `pywin32` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I did install pypiwin32. Turns out something must have gone wrong with my AntiVirus software or it did not register but after restarting my computer and running the pip install once again it fixed itself.

Thank you for answering tho!

Comment: Hi, don't forget to mark your answer to end this thread, other community members can benefit from it. [How to mark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: For me was a similar solution. I uninstalled everything related to win32 and then installed again and magically it worked