# Failed to execute script pyi_rth_win32comgenpy after packing with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pywin32

I'm trying to pack a script that contains these external imports:

```
import keyboards
import win32gui
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pytesseract
```

I have a virtual environment set up with PyCharm, so I make sure to add the site-packages directory to the -paths option when running pyinstaller.

I am at a loss for what to do now since this error has never been fully answered. Some other resources ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425401/py-to-exe-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-win32comgenpy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149838/no-module-named-win32api-py2exe)) say to simply uninstall and then reinstall all packages relating to win32. I did that, but it's still not successful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with it for about an hour, I've come to a solution. I added `--hidden-import "pywin32"` to the pyinstaller command, and it worked! So if uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't work, try adding "pywin32" as a hidden import.